# Raise Error/ Throw Exception for Certain Condition SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, throw, raiserror

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c913b/1

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
[ID] int PRIMARY KEY,
[Date] date,
[Name] varchar(40)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, date, Name )
Values ('1','07-20-18','Fred'),
('2','07-15-18','Sam'),
('3','07-20-18','Ben'),
('4','07-19-18','Simon'),
('5','07-25-18','Dave');
```

Current Query:

```
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME,
@CurrentDate AS DATETIME
SET @StartDate = GETDATE() -30
SET @CurrentDate = GETDATE()
SELECT [ID], [Date], [Name]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @CurrentDate
```

Current result:

```
| ID |       Date |  Name |
|----|------------|-------|
|  1 | 2018-07-20 |  Fred |
|  2 | 2018-07-15 |   Sam |
|  3 | 2018-07-20 |   Ben |
|  4 | 2018-07-19 | Simon |
```

This query compares with the range of day set for the @startdate variable. This can be changed to anything by anyone who wants to run the query. The issue is if someone selects a really large range of dates it crashes. Is there a way i can set an if statement that throws an error message if for example they tried to run a query for longer than 100 days.

Result: ERROR - Please lower the date range

Is this possible at all?

Comment: As for me, the question sounds strange - why would you protect table from specific queries? "By anyone who wants to run this query". Are they developers? If yes, then why would they change query or why wouldn't you let them do this? If they are not developers, then don't give them a query - give them a stored procedure which will validate inputs. If you have procedure level or, even better, application server layer, then it should definitely be done there, but not at table level.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev i understand its strange but is that type of thing possible?

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: It depends. The problem is that I personally can't understand why you need this, I can't understand your case and it seems to be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) question. If I can't understand a cause of the problem, then I can't invent a solution :)

Comment: If you used a stored procedure instead of a straight query, with the start date as a parameter, you could check the `DATEDIFF` between the start date and the current date and raise an error prior if it exceeds a given value.

Comment: "It crashes" - What does this mean? And what is the error? It is far better to fix your application than attempt to avoid this particular error.

Comment: it times out if it is too large. I effectively want to put in a warning if anyone is to mess with the query